# Copy an app via terminal and not just the content

Tags: terminal

I am trying to copy an app from a source (which can be anything, like a DMG mounted on my desktop, or a folder, or just the app on a usb pen drive), using terminal.

I used `cp -fr` since most OSX apps are in fact directories; but when I inspect the file, it does not have the original app icon, and it does not seem to work. I checked the content of the package and seems that everything is there; but for some reasons, OSX does not like it when I run the app.

If I just drag and drop the app via Finder, it works fine; if I copy it via `cp -fr` the app does not have its icon and does not work correctly.

Should I use something else instead of `cp`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. For such cases, `ditto` seems to work much better.

the main advantage of `ditto` is that it preserves ownership attributes and permissions, on top of file resource forks and file and folder metadata. This ensure that everything is copied 1:1.

For OSX apps, it does copy the folder and content exactly as is, and this guarantee that the app will be working correctly.